# Generics specific interface definition in Java

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to define following in Java:

```
public interface IGenericRepo<T> {
    void add();
    void delete();
    void attach();
}

public interface IGenericRepo<Book> {
    default String bookSpecificMethod(){
      return "smthn";
    }
}

public class NHGenericRepo<T> implements IGenericRepo<T>{
    /* implementation */
}

public class NHUnitOfWork implements UnitOfWork{
    @Autowired
    public void setBookRepo(NHGenericRepo<Book> bookRepo) {
        this.bookRepo= bookRepo;
    }
    public NHGenericRepo<Book> getBookRepo() {
       return bookRepo;
    }
    private NHGenericRepo<Book> bookRepo;
}
```

And to be able somewhere in code to have:

```
{
    @Autowired
    public void setNhuw(NHUnitOfWork nhuw) {
        this.nhuw = nhuw;
    }

    private NHUnitOfWork nhuw;

    /**/

    {
        String st = this.nhuw.getBookRepo().bookSpecificMethod();
    }
}
```

In .net this is possible by using Extension Method with "this IGenericRepo<Book>" as a first method parameter.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to implement `IGenericRepo` for `Book`, so `class BookRepo implements IGenericRepo<Book>`?

Comment: Note that Java method names, by convention, start with a lowercase letter (same goes for variable names).

Comment: Note that the leading "I" for interfaces names is a C convention and usually not used in Java.

Comment: just updated my question.

Comment: @bojanv55 "Is it possible": did you try it? Did you have any concrete issues?

Comment: It complains that I cannot have IGenericRepo<T> and IGenericRepo<Book> at same time, because it has the same name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest you can come is:

```
public interface IBookGenericRepo extends IGenericRepo<Book> {
    void BookSpecificMethod();
}
```